# #include <gtest/gtest.h> is not working with fatal error no such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I am trying to test my project, but stuck at including <gtest/gtest.h>. I coppied through git clone googletest and tried to include it, but it throw fatal error:
`fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory`    .

I am using Visual studio code if it metters/

My project structure:

```
    lab-1
     |
     - googletest
     |
     - src  
     |  |
     |   - lab-1.cpp
     |  |
     |   - parser.cpp
     |  |
     |   - parser.hpp
     |
     - test
     |  |
     |   - CMakeLists.txt
     |  |
     |   - tests.cpp
     |
     - CMakeLists.txt
```

`your text`Project CMakeLists.txt:

```
     cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

     set(This lab-1)

     project(${This})

     set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

     include_directories(src)

     add_executable(${This}
        src/lab-1.cpp
        src/parser.hpp
        src/parser.cpp
        )

     add_subdirectory(test)
```

Tests CMakeLists.txt:

```
     include(FetchContent)

     FetchContent_Declare(
        googletest
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
        GIT_TAG v1.14.0
     )

     FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

     enable_testing()

     add_executable(runTests
             tests.cpp
     ../src/parser.hpp
     ../src/parser.cpp)

     include(GoogleTest)

     target_link_libraries(runTests gtest_main gmock)
     gtest_discover_tests(runTests)
```

Send help pls

Including full path to gtest.h
Playing with CMakeLists
Recloning googletest repository

Comment: `target_link_libraries(runTests GTest::gtest GTest::gmock GTest::gmock_main)
`

Comment: @273K didn't help